# Python regex - OR in the middle of the capture group

Tags: python, regex

My code currently looks like this:

```
stat_block = re.search(r"(CR\s+[0-9/]+\s+XP[\S\s]*?)SPECIAL ABILITIES|"
                       r"(CR\s+[0-9/]+\)\s+XP[.\S\s]*?)SPECIAL ABILITIES",
                       text)
```

It should extract something like this:

```
CR 1
XP 200
// ... more text here
SPECIAL ABILITIES
```

or something like this:

```
CR 1/2)
XP 200
// ... more text here
SPECIAL ABILITIES
```

The problem is the closing paren `)` after number after `CR`. I want to create alternative (OR, `|`) to either capture nothing or `)` in the capture group, since ORing two long regexes is quite cumbersome to read. Is that possible? Or how else should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to [...] either capture nothing or ) in the capture group

Anything wrong with `\)?` for an optional match?

```
(CR\s+[0-9/]+\)?\s+XP[.\S\s]*)SPECIAL ABILITIES
```

Comment: @OP, or you can do what you described literally, using a non-capturing group (i.e., `(?:\)|)` = "a closing bracket OR nothing"); there's no need to use OR between two whole patterns. Obviously, `\)?` is sufficient and better in terms of readability though.

Comment: Why a dot in `[.\S\s]*`?

Comment: @Toto - because I forgot to delete it. Tomalak - thanks, that's exactly what I needed!